# How to draw graphics as efficiently as possible in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, graph, vector-graphics

I am creating a tool which relies heavily on graph-node trees. The current implementation is done in Java and I'm porting it to a generic code-base on C#, so it can be used by various rendering implementations and also because I want to use the power of WPF for a user-friendly interface.

After browsing around for a day, I came across various methods to draw Vector-graphics through WPF.

[This guy](http://www.fernicola.org/loquitor/index.php?/archives/17-WPF-Pick-Your-API-Abstraction.html) speaks about different layers within WPF developers can choose from. As I want to use WPF PURELY for his rendering at first, I want to work on the "Visual Layer".

I then came across things like:
[DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx),
[GeometryDrawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrydrawing.aspx),
[FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) / [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx) / Shapes

So, I'm a bit overwhelmed by all the different implementations that do eventually the same in totally different ways.

The Graph-Node library has been ported to C# already with all it's logic (including collision detection and dragging with mouse). As it is made with graphic-renderers in mind (like XNA, SlimDX, OpenTK, etc.), what would be the best way in terms of performance to implement a WPF renderer (as in, it will draw whatever the graph library tells it to draw?

Basically, the resulting WPF control acts as a canvas, but it has to be SUPER lightweight and not have any neat WPF features besides providing me a way to draw my circles, lines and other shapes :)

EDIT:

I basically want to know: What is the way to go? Do I extend Canvas as "Host" for my graphics and then add my custom implementation of a UIElement? Or can I have one class which can draw EVERYTHING (as in, one mega super ultra graphic). Much like overriding OnPaint in GDI or Paint-method in Java (which gives a Graphics object to do everything with).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: How many nodes are you expecting to draw in a normal graph?

Comment: Hundreds, at the very least. Graphs get dynamically generated in iterations. Each iteration can double the number of nodes. I'm starting to think I'd be better of using some kind of DirectX implementation (in terms of culling, perhaps?).

Comment: @Lennard: Remember, WPF uses DirectX under the hood - you get most of that stuff for free.  Canvas+Drawing will easily scale up to thousands of nodes (at least in Vista+), though it's using DirectX, so it's a bit graphics card dependent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd recommend reading [Optimizing Performance: 2D Graphics and Imaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bb613591(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Basically, `Drawing` objects will be lighter weight than `Shapes`, in general. This is probably what you want to use.

Comment: I've read that specific page already and it only made me more confused about what to do and what to pick. All methods described there still seem to be hooked into the framework layer quite a bit, while the Microsoft-blog guy specifically mentioned a Visual Layer without all the fancy stuff.

Comment: I basically want to know: What is the way to go? Do I extend Canvas as "Host" for my graphics and then add my custom implementation of a UIElement? Or can I have one class which can draw EVERYTHING (as in, one mega super ultra graphic). Much like overriding OnPaint in GDI or Paint-method in Java (which gives a Graphics object to do everything with).

Comment: @Lennard: The "Visual Layer" is part of the framework layers.  Everything in WPF uses, and is split, between the visual and logical trees.  In your specific case, it sounds like you want to use GeometryDrawing and the related classes.  This will provide you a clean, (relatively) lightweight way to handle the drawing of your data, without a lot of the other stuff that gets added in by the Shape* classes.

Comment: @Lennard: You don't wnat to think about this like WinForms - you just use Canvas, and add the Drawing objects to it.  WPF will handle the actual rendering for you, and do it quite efficiently, especially if you use DrawingGroup, as it caches things nicely.

Comment: Ok, so WPF doesn't have anything even remotely close to a Graphics object as seen in Java? The closest thing I've seen in WPF is a DrawingContext, but it's limited to one figure per context (or is it?).

Comment: @Lennard: You can use Window.OnRender (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender.aspx) - However, using drawings is typically much better for things like this.  WPF's caching, if you use DrawingGroup, will typically perform **better** then doing your own drawing like you would in Windows Forms/Java.  It caches and renders everything via Direct3D, so it's quite fast.

Comment: Ok, so to recap. I would create a Canvas host object (is there anything lower-level that can be used?) and then Children.Add Drawing-subclasses. And this, according to you, is the most efficient way to draw vector-graphics without all additional unneeded WPF-features?

Comment: @Lennard: That's going to be really good.  If you can use DrawingGroup to "group" together elements that will likely only change as a group, it will make it more efficient still.  (Canvas is pretty low level - it's a good option here.)

Comment: Alright, then I'll just go with the flow. My final question before I can express my never ending gratitude by accepting your answer (which I'm sure is an answer to a question everyone had at some point) is: How would I go about updating the Drawings? In game-engines, you have this massive while loop which updates and renders all objects 60 times a frame (considering it's capped), what would be the way-to-go with WPF?

Comment: @Lennard: WPF is nicer in that you don't update every frame, you just update when something changes.  If you associate a drawing with the actual business object (graph node), you can just change the actual value when things change, and WPF will take care of updating for you...

Comment: Thanks, I can most likely fit that into the design of the library :)

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer no longer works, but I was able to find it in the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20111116042437/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613591.aspx).

Comment: The page moved to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613591(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 8):

Generally, better performance is obtained with lower-level services. In `WPF`, this means the `Drawing` family of objects. All you get are: `Drawing`, `DrawingGroup`, `GeometryDrawing`, `GlyphRunDrawing`, `ImageDrawing`, and `VideoDrawing`. However, they are sufficient for all needs. Using these types is very friendly with WPF because `Drawing` is the conceptual unit that WPF exchanges with your GPU accelerator, possibly retaining and managing it there if possible. This works because the `Drawing` is expressed in terms of portable vector drawing primitives.

Once you start re-architecting your app around `Drawings` however, you might need some interop with your higher-level code which is still based on `UIElement`, `FrameworkElement`, etc. One thing that I haven't found built-in to WPF is a simple way to **wrap a Drawing as a FrameworkElement** in the lowest-overhead way possible. `DrawingVisual` isn't a complete solution, because it only derives from `Visual`--meaning it still requires a hosting element.

The following class will host any WPF `Drawing` directly without using an intermediate `DrawingVisual`. I added support for `FrameworkElement`'s `Margin` property (with no performance penalty if unused) but little else. Because of WPF's single rendering thread it's safe and easy to cache a single TranslateTransform object to implement the margin. I'd recommend that you supply only drawings which have been Frozen; in fact, in the version that I use, I have an assert to that effect in the constructor.

```
public class DrawingElement : FrameworkElement
{
    static readonly TranslateTransform tt_cache = new TranslateTransform();

    public DrawingElement(Drawing drawing)
    {
        this.drawing = drawing;
    }
    readonly Drawing drawing;

    TranslateTransform get_transform()
    {
        if (Margin.Left == 0 && Margin.Top == 0)
            return null;
        tt_cache.X = Margin.Left;
        tt_cache.Y = Margin.Top;
        return tt_cache;
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size _)
    {
        var sz = drawing.Bounds.Size;
        return new Size
        {
            Width = sz.Width + Margin.Left + Margin.Right,
            Height = sz.Height + Margin.Top + Margin.Bottom,
        };
    }
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        var tt = get_transform();
        if (tt != null)
            dc.PushTransform(tt);
        dc.DrawDrawing(drawing);
        if (tt != null)
            dc.Pop();
    }
};
```

[edit:] This is also useful for inserting a WPF `Drawing` into the `InlineUIContainer.Child` property (i.e. using `TextBlock.InlinesCollection` to format the contents of the TextBlock more richly).

Answer (score 1):

the DrawingVisual seems to be a valid choice:

> The DrawingVisual is a lightweight drawing class that is used to
>   render shapes, images, or text. This class is considered lightweight
>   because it does not provide layout or event handling, which improves
>   its performance. For this reason, drawings are ideal for backgrounds
>   and clip art.

source: [Using DrawingVisual Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx)

so this seems to be absolutely what you ask, a Canvas SUPER lightweight.

Comment: Please see my 2 notes in Reed's answer. I'll update my first post to make the question even more specific.

Comment: DrawingVisual dows not seem to be too high level as you are afraid of. if you want to be even more lightweight or native, you can still go for OpenGL even inside WPF. Or read this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912469/directx-and-wpf

Comment: I am aware OpenGL/DirectX works within WPF through a D3DImage. It's just that I want to use WPF for rendering this graph as it already comes with methods to draw shapes, whereas with XNA/Other I would have to make my own library to do that and/or find an existing one (I know a few, but since WPF supports this natively AND it is essentially DirectX...).